# Spellcheck & command-line arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, spell-checking

I have written a spellchecker program that checks the spelling of all words in a file. It should read each word of a file and check whether it is contained in a word list. The program should write the incorrect words to a file and I have received an error message on lines 57-58, saying "type mismatch between void to String" and when I ran it on eclipse, I got an unresolved compilation problem" error. What am I doing wrong so it can run smoothly on both Eclipse & on the command line?  Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SpellChecker {
  public static void readDict(){
    File file = new File ("words.txt");
    ArrayList <String> array = new ArrayList <String> ();

    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner (file).useDelimiter("[A-Za-z]");
        while (input.hasNext()){
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String [] wordArray = line.split(" ");

            for(String str : wordArray){
                array.add(str);
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File is not found.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return;
}

  public static void readFile(){
    File file = new File ("mary.txt");
    String [] array;
    String [] array2 = null;

    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner (file);
        int i = 0;
        array = new String [10];

        while(i < array.length && input.hasNext()){
            String story = input.nextLine();
            String[] storyarray = story.split(" ");
            array2[i] = storyarray[i];
            i++;

            for(i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
                System.out.println(array2[i]);
            }
        input.close();
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File cannot be found.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    args[0] = readDict();
    args[1] = readFile();

    if(args == 4){
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[1]);
    }

}
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

}

Comment: What does `readFile` return?

Comment: -Pillar The program is supposed to write a program that checks the spelling of all words in a file.  It should read each word of a file and check whether it is contained in a word list.  The program should write the incorrect words to a file.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking.  You're doing `args[1] = readFile();`. What do you expect `readFile` to return? Why do you expect that from your code? What does it do to achieve that, technically?

Comment: I'm slightly confused on how to run a program via command prompt on Windows & I didn't know what to assign to args[0] and args[1].

Comment: Forget about your use case for a second and think about Java source code. What does `void` signify? What is the return type of `readFile`?